# Shunting-Yard algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

I've just finished coding a Shunting-Yard algorithm implementation, following Wikipedia's C code example and I've got it to finally work.

However, looking at my code now, the two "worker" methods seem bloated. I was wondering what your opinion was regarding the current code stubs and whether or not they need to be split up and to what extent.

Worker: overriden methods

```
package math;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Implementation of the Shunting-yard algorithm invented by Edsger Dijkstra.
 * Parse 'infix' mathematical expressions, and output to Reverse Polish
 * Notation. Used to then evaluate RPN expression and work out the initial
 * 'infix' expression.
 * 
 * @author Llifon Osian Jones
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class ShuntingYardImpl implements ShuntingYard {

    private final Stack<Operator> operatorStack;
    private final Queue<String> outputQueue;

    /**
     * operatorStack - Store Operator Values. outputQueue - Output queue
     * containing values and operators - RPN.
     */
    public ShuntingYardImpl() {
        operatorStack = new Stack<>();
        outputQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String[] infixToReversePolishNotation(String input) {
        final String[] expression = input.trim().split(" ");

        for (String token : expression) {

            final char op = token.charAt(0); // Validated beforehand.

            if (isOperator(op)) { // if token is an operator
                final Operator op1 = Operator.getOperatorByValue(op);

                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
                    final Operator op2 = operatorStack.peek();

                    final boolean condition1 = (isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(
                            op1, op2) <= 0);
                    final boolean condition2 = (!isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(
                            op1, op2) < 0);
                    if (condition1 || condition2) {
                        outputQueue.add(String.valueOf(operatorStack.pop()
                                .getSymbol()));
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                operatorStack.push(op1);
            } else if (token.equals("(")) { // if token is an open parenthesis
                operatorStack.push(Operator.OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

            } else if (token.equals(")")) { // if token is a closed parenthesis
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()
                        && (operatorStack.peek() != Operator.OPEN_PARENTHESIS)) {
                    outputQueue.add("" + operatorStack.pop().getSymbol());
                }
                operatorStack.pop(); // pop and discard left parenthesis.
            } else if (isNumerical(token)) {
                outputQueue.add(token);
            }

        }

        while (!operatorStack.empty()) { // Empty out remainder.
            outputQueue.add("" + operatorStack.pop().getSymbol());
        }

        return outputQueue.toArray(new String[] {});
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String reversePolishNotationToResult(String[] input) {
        final Stack<String> execution = new Stack<String>();

        for (final String token : input) {
            final char symbol = token.charAt(0);

            if (isOperator(symbol)) {
                final Operator operator = Operator.getOperatorByValue(symbol);

                if (!isParenthesis(operator) && !execution.isEmpty()) {

                    // Stack - FILO (LIFO), 1st pop = "RIGHT" hand expression
                    final String right = String.valueOf(execution.pop());

                    if (right.equals("0")
                            && symbol == Operator.DIVIDE.getSymbol()) {
                        return "Division By Zero";
                    }

                    if (!execution.isEmpty()) {
                        // Stack - FILO (LIFO), 2nd pop = "LEFT" hand expression
                        final String left = String.valueOf(execution.pop());
                        final BigDecimal result = MathUtils.evaluateExpression(
                                left, right, symbol);
                        // Push latest result back into the stack.
                        execution.push(result.toPlainString());
                    }

                }
            } else {
                execution.push(token); // push numbers into stack.
            }
        }

        return execution.isEmpty() ? "Error" : execution.pop();
    }

    /**
     * Tests whether or not an Operator represents parenthesis.
     * 
     * @param operator
     *            Object to evaluate.
     * @return True if the operator is either "(" or ")".
     */
    private boolean isParenthesis(Operator operator) {
        return operator == Operator.OPEN_PARENTHESIS
                || operator == Operator.CLOSED_PARENTHESIS;
    }

    /**
     * Test if an Operator object is assigned Left or Right Associativity.
     * 
     * @param op
     *            Operator object to evaluate.
     * @return True if assigned LEFT, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isLeftAssociative(Operator op) {
        return op.getAssociativity() == Associativity.LEFT;
    }

    /**
     * Test if input matches a numerical format: E.g - 23, 23.1, 2, 1000.
     * 
     * @param input
     *            String to evaluate
     * @return True if a valid number.
     */
    private boolean isNumerical(String input) {
        final char[] tokens = input.toCharArray();

        for (char c : tokens) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != '.') {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Test if current CHAR matches a valid Operator specification. Operator
     * defined in OPERATOR ENUM, but excluding parenthesis.
     * 
     * @param op
     *            Character value of a supposed operator.
     * @return True if 'op' matches an Operator value, excluding parenthesis.
     */
    private boolean isOperator(char op) {
        final Operator operator = Operator.getOperatorByValue(op);

        if (operator != null) {
            final boolean isParenthesis = operator.getAssociativity() == Associativity.NONE;
            if (!isParenthesis) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Compares the 'priority' level of two Operator enums. Priority determined
     * by precedence values of Operator enums.
     * 
     * @param op1
     *            Operator 1 to compare
     * @param op2
     *            Operator 2 to compare
     * @return ( -1 if op1 < op2 ), ( 0 if op1 == op2 ), ( 1 if op1 > op2 ).
     */
    private int compareOperators(Operator op1, Operator op2) {
        final int op1V = op1.getPrecedence();
        final int op2V = op2.getPrecedence();

        if (op1V < op2V) {
            return -1;
        } else if (op1V == op2V) {
            return 0;
        }
        // op1v > op2v
        return 1;

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShuntingYardImpl syi = new ShuntingYardImpl();

        String input = "( 10.2 + ( 2 ^ 4 ) ) + ( 2 - 2 )";
        String[] array = syi.infixToReversePolishNotation(input);
        System.out.println("Answer = "
                + syi.reversePolishNotationToResult(array));
    }

}
```

Related to the question: Is it a bad sign when conditional statements span so widely?

I tried to clean them up by assigning values to `boolean` variables, but it still looks a tad ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad "wide conditional statements":

```
if (isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 1
    || !isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 0) {
    // ...
}
```

is not equal to your refactoring:

```
final boolean condition1 = isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 1;
final boolean condition2 = !isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 0;

if (condition1 || condition2) {
    // ...
}
```

because you loose [evaluation short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You can get it back by chaining:

```
boolean condition = isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 1;
condition = condition || !isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 0;

if (condition) {
    // ...
}
```

or by deferring the evaluation:

```
interface Condition { boolean eval(); }

final Condition condition1 = new Condition() {
    @Override
    public boolean eval() {
        return isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 1;
    }
};
final Condition condition2 = new Condition() {
    @Override
    public boolean eval() {
        return !isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators(op1, op2) < 0;
    }
};

if (condition1.eval() || condition2.eval()) {
    // ...
}
```

In general, instead of conditions themselves, you should precompute those expensive calls that have to be performed **in any case**:

```
final int compareOperators = compareOperators(op1, op2);

if (compareOperators < 0 || isLeftAssociative(op1) && compareOperators < 1) {
    // ...
}
```

while in your code, a more concise option is:

```
if (compareOperators(op1, op2) < (isLeftAssociative(op1) ? 1 : 0)) {
    // ...
}
```

But in fact, instead of returning `int` from `compareOperators()`, you should introduce and return an `enum` like:

```
enum Precedence { LOWER, EQUAL, HIGHER; }
```

which would break some of the approaches outlined above.

Comment: Awesome answer Charlie, real intense ;p. I never knew short circuit evaluations existed, I always believed all conditions were tested regardless (in this scenario), so thanks. Could I get your opinion on nesting an interface like that inside a class? Is it still good practice? I always try to split any interface or classes to their own source file as I've always felt it is what is expected, it just often gets ugly with many parameters and added coupling.

Comment: From *Effective Java* -- **Minimize the accessibility of classes and members**: You should always reduce accessibility as much as possible. You should prevent any class, interface or member from becoming a part of the API. This concept, known as encapsulation, is one of the fundamental tenets of software design.
• If a top-level class or interface can be made package-private, it should be. If a package-private
top-level class or interface is used only from within a single class, you should consider making it a **private nested class (or interface)** of the class in which it is used.

Comment: Well now that totally flips what I've been taught on its head! Ever considered being a lecturer? I've learnt at least 2 things from you today :D. Thanks Charlie.

Comment: You may think it goes against the [code reuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse), but it doesn't. It's just a way to limit & control entry points, to hide internal specifics to be able to change them in the future without breaking API clients, and to ensure [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). For **package-private** classes (or interfaces) it doesn't make any difference if you keep them in a separate file, or not. Anybody can declare a new class in "your" package to get access to its internals. You can prevent it only by using **`private`**, i.e. nesting.

Comment: But please, don't get an impression that you should start nesting everything from now on. You can't totally prevent a misuse of your code (e.g. by reflection). If somebody invades "your" package, it's his design flaw, not yours. Still, nesting is good for _loose coupling_ **inside** your package.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend creating a `Token` class with specialized sub-classes for things like operators, parenthesis and values/identifiers. Your pre-defined tokens can all be saved in a Map so that you can access them quickly. The big loops that go through the token stream and "if it's an  do the  thing" logic can all be moved to the specialized `Token` instances. The body of the loop then becomes: 1) convert text to `Token`, 2) have the `Token` do it's thing.

Comment: Thanks Donald, I've taken on what you've suggested and I've also replaced the Stack with a Deque implementation of a Stack, of which I'm led to believe is far superior to the old Vector implementation of the concrete Stack class.